# Minimal prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Can we prove that there exist an ideal $p\subset P$ such that $p$ is a minimal prime ideal? (I think it might be used Axiom of Choice?) If $R$ is Noetherian, can we avoid to use Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Do you mean does there exist an ideal $p$ that satisfies this property?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent characterization of $P$ being a prime ideal is that its complement $R\setminus P$ is a multiplicative system, ie. is closed under multiplication and containing the $1$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of multiplicative systems, which contain the complement of $P$ as subsystem. It is partially ordered by inclusion, obviously nonempty and the union of ascending chains of multiplicative systems yields a multiplicative system (that is to say: ascending chains have an upper bound). By Zorn there is a maximal element, which corresponds to a minimal prime ideal.

I am not sure, how noetherianess affects this argument. Maybe there is another argument, which can be simplified by it.

Comment: @PrudiiArca Thanks for your comments, but I do not know how to use Zorn to know: every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal, can you explain more?

Comment: @Duke You are welcome. I added some more details.

Comment: @PrudiiArca Can you explain why maximal element corresponds to a minimal prime ideal？R\P means elements in R not in P?

Comment: Yes, $R\setminus P = \{r \in R \mid r \notin P\}$ denotes the set theoretic complement. And taking complements is inclusion reversing. I would propose drawing the Venn diagrams yourself to get a feel for this. I doubt that I can explain that (maximal system = minimal prime) part much better...